# What's easier to encrypt on iPhone: Core Data or Property Lists?

Tags: iphone, encryption, core-data, passwords, property-list

What type of persistent data storage would be easier to encrypt on the iPhone- core data, or property lists?  By "easier" I mean require less time and complicated steps to implement.

Comment: Do you just want to encrypt the file, or do you want to encrypt the data in the file?

Comment: Data in the file.  For example if the user wanted to create an account with a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For storing passwords safely, you should probably be using [Keychain Services](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html).

Comment: Yeah, but the Keychain Services has a notoriously complicated API.  There's this: http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code but I'm uncertain how good this is.

Comment: (1) Well that code worked for me. Yes it was a bit more complex then the bare minimum I needed (remembering only ONE username/password), but so are the bare Keychain APIs. The reason I used it was because it worked in the simulator 6 months ago, and they Keychain APIs didn't at that time (no idea if this has been fixed yet).

Comment: (2) Though notoriously complicated, I still think the Keychain is the right way to store login/passwords. It's easier to use it than to build your own encrypted-storage solution that's truly secure, and free of subtle issues. Just my $0.02.

Comment: Sorry I didn't ask you this earlier.  Thanks a lot for your responses.  Could you possibly take a look at this, please?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870000/has-anyone-used-buzz-andersens-simple-iphone-keychain-code